# why doesn't attribute in a model work in Rails SIMPLE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

new to rails/ruby, so this (i think) is a very straightforward question. Why doesn't this work in my model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    attribute :email, :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
end
```

I get the error

```
undefined method `attribute' for #<Class:0x00000101218ed0>
```

The model does exist, as does the column (or attribute?) 'email', so surely I must be able to validate its submission like so.

Comment: Please see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

Comment: It should be `validates :email, format: { with: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails [**`format`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) helper *validates the attributes' values by testing whether they match a given regular expression, which is specified using the :with option*

Try:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i,message: "your validation message" }
end
```

If you are using **rails 3.x** then you need **`validates_format_of`**

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
```